# upgrade errors from web client .net core 3.1 to httpclient .net 6.0

Tags: c#, upgrade, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1

i am upgrading my .net core 3.1 solution to .net 6.0 but facing issue in WebClient of System.Net and after upgrading solution to .net 6.0 i am using HttpClient of System.Net.Http. i want to convert the code of .net core 3.1 to .net 6.0

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Key", Key);
                return client.DownloadString(url);
            }
```

the above code i want to convert to .net 6.0
i have tried following thing i don't know what to use for **DownloadString** in .net 6.0 i have used **GetAsync** but not sure what to use **GetAsync** or **Send**. Same for **UploadString**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Key", Key);
                return client.GetAsync(Url + action);
            }
```

also i am getting error if i used GetAsync that

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' to
> 'string'

Can anybody help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). That won't solve your problem, but it's still something you need to fix. Then, you need to read the [documentation about using async/await in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), which will arm you with the knowledge necessary to resolve this properly.

Comment: @mason i have read the doc but i am not getting what is UploadString/Download String is doing

Comment: webclient.DownloadString [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=net-6.0).